# Angular Cli Error: Unexpected token ] in JSON at position 1008

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6

I'm having a problem with generate components and services.
I get the error "Unexpected token ] in JSON at position 1008"
The only file I had which was that long was package-lock.json but even after I used rm package-lock.json I still got the same error message (although I don't have the file).
I could add components on cli before, and I don't know what have changed that now I can't.
I'm putting the recent files I changed and the json files here:

**angular.json**

```css
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "LG-Academy": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "lg",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "styleext": "sass"
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/LG-Academy",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.sass",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss",
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "LG-Academy:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "LG-Academy:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "LG-Academy:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.sass"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "LG-Academy-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "LG-Academy:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "LG-Academy:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "LG-Academy"
}
```

**package.json**

```css
{
  "name": "lg-academy",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.1.0",
    "angular-font-awesome": "^3.1.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.8",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.8",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1"
  }
}
```

**./courses/course.service**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { map, tap, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { ICourse } from './course';

@Injectable()
export class CourseService{
  private courseUrl = 'http://localhost:300/courses.json';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
}
```

**/.courses/course-list/course-list.component**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

import { ICourse } from '../course';
import { CourseService } from '../course';

@Component({
  selector: 'lg-course-list',
  templateUrl: './course-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./course-list.component.sass']
})

export class CourseListComponent implements OnInit {
  pageTitle = "LabGuru Academy";

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() { }

}
```

**/.courses/course.ts**

```js
export interface ICourse {
  course_id: number;
  title: string;
  autor: string;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove tariling comma at line:
"node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss",

Comment: OMG I didn't notice that! I feel stupid haha Thank you so much!

Comment: Not always but when errors say something about "unexpected token", it's because there is a malformed json object. In your case was a fairly big object so to debug that you can use a json validator like https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/